# Can't use reset --hard on individual file?

Tags: git, git-reset

I had a patch I wanted to apply on a fresh branch, and commit.
(I was trying to rescue myself from the problem described at
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77784030).)
So I did

```
git apply patchfile
git add file1
git add file2
git add file3
git add file4
```

where `file1..4` were the four files I knew I was patching.

But when I then checked my work, with `git status` or `git diff --cached`,
prior to committing to my new branch, I discovered that, for some
as-yet-unknown reason, only `file1` and `file2` had been patched.

I want to retry the `git apply` to see what went wrong, but first
I have to reset things to their initial state.
That feels like `git reset` on at least `file1` and `file2`, but
since I've already added those files to the cache, I'm pretty
sure I want `reset --hard`.  But when I do

```
git reset --hard file1
```

it says `fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths`.

I'm sure there's a good reason for this, and (whatever it is) it
probably means that `reset --hard` was *not* what I wanted to do.
Can anyone explain?

(Perhaps I just wanted a fresh `git checkout`, not necessarily `git reset`.
I guess I'm not sure what the difference is between checkout and reset.)

---

Update: This question is confused, and doesn't make much sense.  I suspect I'll delete it soon.

Mostly I wanted to undo a `git add`, and I had misread my notes, and concluded that `reset --hard` was what I wanted.  But no, that's wrong; the way to undo a `git add` is with a simple `git reset`.  No `--hard` required.  (And then, having reset the index, I believe I do want a `git checkout` to restore the working file, as suggested by Tim Roberts in a comment.)

Comment: `git restore file1`? (it's even output in the `git status` hint). Or correspondingly `git restore --staged file1` if you already have staged it.

Comment: In git, a commit contains the entire state of the repository.  `git reset` changes the head commit, which changes ALL of the files.  Did you want `git checkoiut`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+checkout+reset+restore Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15404733/7976758

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, and I'm sure `restore` is a good command to know about, but it's not present in the version of git on the machine where I had the problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, in retrospect I believe I do want `git checkout`, after a regular (not hard) reset.  Thanks.